# Permutation with BigInteger

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, biginteger

Permutation with `BigInteger` works fine upto 4 digits (3456 P 1234) when i give 5 digit input to n and r, it is not working. i have changed my input type as   `BigInteger n = scan.nextBigInteger();`I edited my code as

`

```
    import java.math.BigInteger;
    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class cvic {
 public static void main(String[] args)
{   
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Enter n and r: ");
BigInteger n = scan.nextBigInteger();
BigInteger r = scan.nextBigInteger();

System.out.println("nPr = "+fact(n).divide(fact(n.subtract(r))));
}
 static BigInteger fact(BigInteger num) {        
 BigInteger fa = BigInteger.ONE;      
for(BigInteger inte = BigInteger.ONE; inte.compareTo(num) <= 0; inte = inte.add(BigInteger.ONE)){            
fa = fa.multiply(inte);
    }        
    return fa;
    }
          }
```

`

Comment: "my code is not working" is *never* enough information. You need to tell us the expected results and the actual results, at least. You should also edit your post so it's properly formatted.

Comment: Are you typing your integers in when the program starts?

Comment: yes i can give inputs, after that nothing takes place.

Comment: `for(inte.equals(1);...` Don't think that's right..

Comment: Please follow Java's [naming conventions and coding standards](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html). They aren't optional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an endless for loop, so your application never ends.

```
static BigInteger fact(BigInteger bv) {        
    BigInteger fa = BigInteger.ONE;      
    for(BigInteger inte = BigInteger.ONE; inte.compareTo(bv) <= 0; inte = inte.add(BigInteger.ONE)){            
        fa = fa.multiply(inte);
    }        
    return fa;
}
```

Comment: can u please tell me how to fix this?

Comment: Who downvoted this answer?  It is 100% correct!  If it was OP, it is fairly audacious to downvote and then ask again for help on how to fix.

Comment: this is  my first time to ask questions in this forum.i dont knw how to vote and all.

Comment: Thanks @Trenin, that's OK. Kruthika, I updated with my example

Comment: @Kruthika OK - Sorry for the tone of my comment.

Comment: But it works upto 4 digit inputslike n=2345 r=1234 and answer is not coming for 5 digit inputs.

Comment: That is because the calculation takes too long. The answer will come out eventually, but larger the number, longer it needs to calculate the factorial. However you can make some optimizations in your code. It seems that you want to count the permutations n!/(n-r)!. The upper part of the formula already contains the (n-r)! in itself. So you are calculating that part twice and then deleting it. Just calculate the multiplication of numbers from (n-r) to n.

Answer (score 2):

You have an infinite loop in your program:

```
for(inte.equals(1);inte.compareTo(BigInteger.ZERO)>=0;inte.add(BigInteger.ONE))
```

- `inte.equals(1)` always evaluates to `true` and as a bonus does nothing.
- `inte.compareTo(BigInteger.ZERO) >= 0` is always `true` (that's why the `for` loop will never terminate) because `inte` is always equal to 1
- `inte.add(BigInteger.ONE)` - returns a new `BigInteger` and doesn't modify `inte` (`BigInteger` is an immutable class) - hence `inte` will always be equal to 1.

What you want is probably (I assume what you want is: calculate a factorial of `bv`):

```
while (inte.compareTo(bv) <= 0) {
  fa = fa.multiply(inte);
  inte = inte.add(BigInteger.ONE);
}
```

Correct handling of `fact(0)` is left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: Can also be `for(inte = BigInteger.ONE; inte.compareTo(bv)<=0; inte = inte.add(BigInteger.ONE)`

Answer (score 0):

You need to bound your for loop by `bv` instead of zero.  Also, you need to increment `inte` properly, as suggested in another answer.